# Persist Capybara Session for 2FA

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails

I am trying to write an end-to-end tests with Capybara and I think that Capybara doesnt have a session which means I cant even get to my 2FA step.

I tried to check with this:

```
Capybara.current_session.driver.request.cookies #=> {}
```

Is there a way to force (or manually set) a Capybara session across multiple tests or visit multiple pages within the same test, so that I can login a testuser fill out a couple forms => login form + 2FA form and then proceed with some functionality I need to test?

Here is an example:

```
def enter_password_and_email(email, password)
    visit "/login"
    fill_in "login_email", with: email
    fill_in "login_password", with: password
    click_button "Login"
end

def enter_two_factor_auth_code
    totp = ROTP::TOTP.new("secret").now
    fill_in "login_otp_attempt", with: totp
    click_button "Verify"
end
```

When I run those the #enter_password_and_email works and I even reach the 2FA page (I can see the response.body) but then the #enter_two_factor_auth_code never hits the relevant controller action and sends me to the invalid email or password page.

Comment: What exactly is supposed to happen when you click the "Verify" button? What driver are you using with Capybara?  Are you sure the "secret" matches the one being used by your app for the user with the given email?

Comment: I dont think the verify button is the problem but ideally it would hit the two-factor-authentication in my app. But without the same session i guess it interprets it as the first time the login action is hit and places me on the invalid password/email page instead of logging in.
likewise the secret doesnt matter (yet) as we never hit the action.
as for drivers I havent tinkered with capybara so it should be the default (selenium firefox?)